# why I'm getting this error "Input 0 of layer "dense_30" is incompatible with the layer:expected min_ndim=2,found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)"

Tags: tensorflow

Set random seed

```
print(np.__version__) tf.random.set_seed(42)
```

1. Create a model using the Sequential Api

   ```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
   ```
2. Compile the model

   ```
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,# mae is short for mean absolute error
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), # sgd is short for stochastic gradient descent             
    metrics=["mae"]
   ```
3. Fit the model

   ```
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=5) // here the error
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an input layer, ex:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,)),  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) ])
```